# Add text next to button in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to add text next to `Play / Mute button`

[image]

Here's my script:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('tune.xm');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    SoundStream := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\tune.xm'), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False);

    SoundCtrlButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    SoundCtrlButton.Parent := WizardForm;
    SoundCtrlButton.Left := 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
      SoundCtrlButton.Height - 8;
    SoundCtrlButton.Width := 40;
    SoundCtrlButton.Caption :=
      ExpandConstant('{cm:SoundCtrlButtonCaptionSoundOff}');
    SoundCtrlButton.OnClick := @SoundCtrlButtonClick;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you are adding the button. Create a new control ([`TLabel`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TLabel)) and add it to the form by assigning the `WizardForm` to the control's `Parent` property.

A basic code to add a label is:

```pascal
var
  MyLabel: TLabel;
begin
  MyLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  MyLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  MyLabel.Left := ...;
  MyLabel.Top := ...;
  MyLabel.Caption := '...';
end;
```

Putting it together without your code and positioning the label relatively to the button:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  TuneLabel: TLabel;
begin
  ...
  if ... then
  begin
    ...
    SoundCtrlButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    ...

    { Creating a new TLabel control }
    TuneLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
    { Adding it to the wizard form }
    TuneLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
    { Setting caption }
    TuneLabel.Caption := 'tune';
    { Aligning it to the right of the button }
    TuneLabel.Left := SoundCtrlButton.Left + SoundCtrlButton.Width + ScaleX(8);
    { Vertically aligning it with the button }
    { Doing this only after the caption is set and the label is auto-sized. } 
    TuneLabel.Top :=
      SoundCtrlButton.Top + ((SoundCtrlButton.Height - TuneLabel.Height) div 2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Phew! For the first time I get it right. My head hurts :) Thank you very much @martin!